# Is it possible to initialize a variable and then output the same variable using if statements?

Tags: applescript

I'm using "My Touch Bar My Rules" to configure a new button. The preset allows one to add code in a string format. I am trying to code a shuffle button for Spotify that doesn't disappear when Spotify is closed.

I am trying to initialize a new variable ("msg") of which the output will change according to the state of the "shuffle" boolean (true/false). The shuffle button only shows "error", and not the state of the shuffle variable based on spotify.

Code below:

```
{
    {"type": "appleScriptTitledButton", "source": 
    {"inline": "property msg: \"\" 
         if application \"Spotify\" is running then 
         tell application \"Spotify\" 
         if player state is playing then
         if shuffling is true then
         set msg to \"on\" 
         else 
         set msg to \"off\" 
         then
         return msg
         end if
         else 
         return msg 
         end if 
         end tell 
         end if
         return \"\""},
}
```

Comment: Copy the script string in the Script Editor, replace all occurrences of `\r` with a real newline character and remove the backslashes. You will see that the script doesn't compile. The `if - else if - end if` expressions are not balanced (check the `then` statements). And you will get a *variable not defined* error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to coding. Do you have any tips for balancing? I don't see the mistake. Thanks in advance

Comment: The `then` before `return msg` is wrong. And actually the first `return msg` line is supposed to be executed **after** `end if`.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. Could you explain why the then is wrong? I don't really understand its purpose yet... Edit: are they simply used to connect multiple if-statements together?.

Also: your change seemed to do the trick. The only problem is that when I quit spotify, the shuffle icon disappears....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **then** part of an **if** statement needs to be on the same line as the conditional, so the actual script should be something like:

```
property msg: ""

if application "Spotify" is running then
   tell application "Spotify"
      if player state is playing then
         if shuffling is true then
            set msg to "on" 
         else
            set msg to "off"
         end if
      else
         return msg
      end if
   end tell
end if
return ""
```

Which would translate (not tested) to:

```
{"inline": "property msg: \"\" \rif application \"Spotify\" is running then\rtell application \"Spotify\"\rif player state is playing then\rif shuffling is true then\rset msg to \"on\"\relse\rset msg to \"off\"\rend if\relse\rreturn msg\rend if\rend tell\rend if\rreturn \"\""}
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer! Could you explain to me what the then part is doing? I didn't write the script myself fully, as you might have realized ;)
P.S.: do you know why, if Spotify is closed, the button disappears? I thought that storing the value of shuffle in the variable "msg" could then allow to display the latest status even after closing spotify..

Comment: Take a look at the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-158244) for documentation about the **if** statement.  I don’t use MTMR, so all I can do is make a guess that the button disappears because your script returns a blank string if Spotify isn’t running.